# I have a question anyone answer me please quickly

Tags: wordpress

I have a website that is free for hosting or domain, but that website is not secure. When I changed it from https to http, I got another error. This site can’t provide a secure connection.
Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately this site is strictly a forum for programming. Your best bet might be to contact support of your host

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install an SSL certificate. If you are using cPanel I'm sure you can get Lets Encrypt SSL free.